# Break Out the CRV as a distinct part of the purchase price

Tags: phrase-meaning, american-english, phrasal-verbs

I have a question about the usage of "break out" in this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/California_Redemption_Value):

> The charge for California Redemption Value is similar to Bottle Bill deposits used in other states, but is technically a regulatory fee[3] imposed on the distributor of the beverage. The fee tends to be passed along to the retailer and to the consumer via normal market forces. Distributors and retailers usually ***break out the CRV*** as a distinct part of the purchase price in advertising and on receipts.

I cannot find a dictionary definition for this usage of "***break out***".  Could it be wrong, or technical jargon?

Comment: Merriam-Webster gives an accurate breakdown of the possible meanings here:

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/break%20out

Do any of the definitions fit the context of your sentence?

Answer (score 1):

With respect to @mike's comment, it appears that the third definition is the most fitting here:

> to separate from a mass of data <break out newsstand sales>

So it would mean that the CRV is separated from the other components of the price (like net value, other taxes, etc.) and listed on its own.